# Not Assuming Choice, Nilradical Not Equal to Intersection of Prime Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Every proof I’ve seen that, for a commutative ring $A$, $$\newcommand{\Nil}{\operatorname{Nil}}\Nil(A)=\bigcap_{x\in \newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}\Spec(A)}x$$ assumes Zorn’s lemma. So my question is,

Within ZF but not ZFC, does there exist a commutative unital ring $A$ such that $\Nil(A)\neq ∩_{x∈ \Spec(A)}x$? (Here, I define the nilradical to be the set of nilpotents of $A$.)

Perhaps it’s better to *define* $\Nil(A)$ to be the standard conclusion in commutative algebra, obfuscating this (potential?) issue, but I’m still curious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure.  For instance, let $A=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})/\mathrm{fin}$ be the Boolean ring of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ modulo the ideal of finite subsets.  So explicitly, an element of $A$ is an equivalence class of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ where two sets are equivalent if they differ by finitely many elements, addition is symmetric difference, and multiplication is intersection.  A prime ideal in $A$ is equivalent to a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$.  There are models of ZF in which there are no nonprincial ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$, and so $A$ has no prime ideals.  So the intersection of all primes ideals is all of $A$, but not all of $A$ is nilpotent (in fact, the only nilpotent element is $0$).

Comment: Suppose BPI fails, let $X$ be a set and $F$ a filter which does not extend to an ultrafilter over $X$ (i.e., an example of the failure of BPI), then $\mathcal P(X)/F$ would be an example of a Boolean ring without prime ideals?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: So we have an equivalent choice principle.

Comment: Great, thank you both much. I’d never heard of BPI. It’s cute how both this and “every c.ring with 1 has a maximal ideal” are equivalent to choice inside ZF. I wonder just how many of these basic commutative algebra assertions are equivalent to choice within ZF!

Comment: @categoricalimperative: BPI is strictly weaker than choice, not equivalent.

Comment: Oh, I see. Mia culpa